# Resizable DIV making textbox on new line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a DIV element which has a `<label></label>` and input textbox inside it.

Basically, I have enabled jQuery .resizable() on the DIV element but when you make the DIV element smaller than it currently is, the textbox is pushed onto a new line when the DIV right side, starts to touch the textbox.

I tried using min-width on the resizable and DIV, but its not quite was I expected as the value really needs to be the size of the label - this issue still occours when the DIV size touches the textbot.

```
<div id='div1' style='width:300px'>
    <label>Test&nbsp;
        <input type='text' style='width:100px' id='inputBox'/>
    </label>
</div>

$("#div1").resizable({
    handles: "e, w, sw, ne, nw, se"
});
```

I also have this, butwhen the DIV side catches up and the "right" side of the DIV touches the Textbox it then moves it to a new line under the label... I want to continue resizing the textbox but stop it from going onto a new line:

```
$(".ui-resizable-e")
.mousedown(function() {
    $(window).mousemove(function() {
        isDragging = true;
        $(window).unbind("mousemove");
        var width = $('#inputBox').width();
        var parentWidth = $("#div1").offsetParent().width();
        var percent = 100*width/parentWidth+50;

        $("#inputBox").css({'width': percent + '%'});

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First to answer your question you can use the following to prevent wrapping:

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

However I think you're trying to create a horizontal re-sizable text box? Would the following work for you? By adding some extra CSS it resizes the text box without dropping onto the next line.

Sorry if I've misunderstood your request.

HTML:

```
<div id='div1' style='width:300px; border: 1px solid black; white-space:nowrap; padding-right: 50px;'>
    <label>Test&nbsp;
        <input type='text' style='width:100%;' id='inputBox'/>
    </label>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9xrP6/

Comment: That is excellent, thank you so much. Yes you are correct, that is exactly what I am after. My only issue is, even after copying the code it seems the 100% textbox is taking into account the label size aswell. So my handles (and black border applied) appear almost in the middle of the textbox. Not after it? I cannot see any difference in the code!

Comment: Its like the textbox width is 100% of the whole div, which then makes it larger than where the handles are. Not 100% of the remaining space?